# waypoints between one terminal to another terminal required

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image: waypoints between munich and room required]

hi i am writing a google map api code by which i am getting waypoints between origin to destination,code works fine it's give only those waypoints which has terminal (in below image marked as ire ,re , ice, cnl)  .As you see there is lots of distance between 'cnl' and point 'B'. so i want more waypoints between 'CNL' and 'B'. can anybody tell me how i can get this?

i am using this request

```
  var request = {
  origin: start,
  destination: end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT    
   };
```

and this thing for showing waypoints.

```
          for (var j = 0; j < myRoute.legs.length; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.legs[j].steps.length; i++) {
          path=path+myRoute.legs[j].steps[i].start_point+"|";
      }
      }
```

Comment: Running GUI as root is potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy solution. In other travel modes like `google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING`, `google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING`, etc you could use this:

```
var request = { 
  origin: start,
  destination: end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
  waypoints: [
    {
      location:"Some direction",
      stopover:true
    },{
      location:"Verona",
      stopover:true
    }]
};
```

but unfortunately for `TRANSIT` mode waypoints[] option will be ignored. Of course you may try to merge several direction request in a single route but that will require more work and transit time may be tricky to calculate.